# Install apache2 sqlite3 git - Ansible Loop

Tags: ansible

I have read all the similar questions here and yet I don't see a solution that fixed my issue.

This is my code:

```
---
- name: install apache2, sqlite3, git
  
  tasks:
    - name: Install list of packages
      apt:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        state: installed
      with_items:
        - apache2
        - sqlite3
        - git
```

Here is the error:

```
ERROR! unexpected parameter type in action: <class 'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleSequence'>
The error appears to be in '/projects/challenge/fresco_loops/tasks/main.yml': line 2, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
The offending line appears to be:
---
- name: install apache2, sqlite3, git
  ^ here
```

I am not really an  ansible expert and this is just one of the trainings we have to take. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your play does not have the required `hosts` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

firstly the best way to install multiple packages is shown below:

```
---
- name: install apache2, sqlite3, git
  hosts: localhost # run locally
  become: yes
  
  tasks:
  - name: Install list of packages
    apt:
      state: present
      name:
      - apache2
      - sqlite3
      - git
```

And a couple of final points:

- "installed" is not a valid option for apt, try "present".
- package installation requires sudo (`become: yes`).
- To run the code above, which is locally on the node where the playbook sits, you need to use the command: `ansible-playbook playbook.yml --ask-become-pass` and enter the sudo password when prompted.

---

Secondly when I tried to run your code I got the following error

```
[DEPRECATION WARNING]: Invoking "apt" only once while using a loop via squash_actions is deprecated. Instead of using a loop to supply multiple items and specifying `name: "{{ item }}"`, please use `name: ['apache2', 'sqlite3', 
'git']` and remove the loop. This feature will be removed in version 2.11. Deprecation warnings can be disabled by setting deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.
failed: [localhost] (item=['apache2', 'sqlite3', 'git']) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": ["apache2", "sqlite3", "git"], "msg": "value of state must be one of: absent, build-dep, fixed, latest, present, got: installed"}
```

When using Ansible 2.9.6, if you are using a different version that might explain it? Its always worth telling people what version you are using, in case the problem is version-specific.

Otherwise your code snippet is not representative of what is actually giving you the error.

Comment: @P Burke
Hello. My ansible version is 2.9.17

I tried running the code snippet you gave me and I still got the error message I had earlier :(

Comment: Hi, that is very odd as the code snippet works fine for me. Can you get *any* ansible playbook to run, even one that just prints a message? If so then try turning it into the snippet, one line and a time, and see where it goes wrong? Otherwise it might be time to re-install Ansible. What OS are you using?

Comment: @PBurke please check your editor's settings and make sure it is using spaces and **not tabs** for indentation. Yaml indentation can only be done with spaces, literal tab characters will not be interpreted correctly.

Comment: @Zeitounator, my code is definitely using spaces (vscode `spaces: 2`); confirmed with hexdump. Or was that a question for @faeri?

Comment: @P Burke Hi, the ansible program is just in hackkerank. It's not actually installed in my device. 

@Zeitounator Hi, yes i used spaces and not tabs

Comment: @faeri, I've no idea what hackkerank is. Try running your code on a normal operating system (linux or Windows) if you can.